# I want to click on a random part of a webpage with ActionChains

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Like mentioned in the question, I want to click on a completely random part of the webpage.

This my current script with Python 3:

```
while int(seconds) > 0:
    try:
        x = random.randint(10, 1200)
        y = random.randint(100, 800)

       #Clicks random part of the page
       upperleft.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x, y)
       upperleft.click()
       upperleft.perform()
       time.sleep(0.1)

       seconds = seconds - 1
       back = back + 1

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       time.sleep(0.1)
       seconds = seconds - 1
       back = back + 1
```

Element is an element in the upper left corner of the page.
I'm aware that this script sometimes clicks at nothing. However I always get this error message:

*stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document*

This is my size of the window:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,900")
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Addition:**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="back-to-nike-link d-sm-ib va-sm-m pt2-sm pb2-sm prl7-sm d-sm-ib"]')
```

This is the element on nike.com/launch in the upper left.

Comment: What is the element you have in 'element,' variable

Comment: What is upper left variable

Comment: Added it to the main question. Sorry, I should have thought of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because sometimes Selenium does not find anything to click on. And yes, the script sometimes clicks at nothing, which is not a huge problem for me.